# How can i make a jsp page (on facebook as a facebook tab) fan gate enabled?

Tags: facebook, jsp

I have made a facebook application in JSP. Then i integrated that application to my facebook page as a tab. 
Now i want a fangate on that facebook tab.
that is i want to make that tab as reveal tab.

How can i do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web application will need code that will request and decode the "signed_request" form variable that Facebook passes to the fan page.

1. Request the second parameter of the "signed_request" string form
   variable.
2. This parameter contains user data encoded in JSON format.
3. Parse the string into a JSONObject.
4. Query the object to find the Boolean "liked" parameter within the
   "page" parameter.
5. You can now specify conditional content based on that parameter.

Note that you will need to add your iFrame application as a tab to a Facebook fan page before you can do any testing. This is because the application will only be passed non-trivial user data from Facebook if it is within the context of a fan page tab.

Here is a tuturial using PHP:
http://www.chilipepperdesign.com/2011/02/15/reveal-fan-gate-like-gate-facebook-iframe-tab-tutorial-with-php

And an overview on "signed_request":
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/